# Using generics and jpa EntityManager methods

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, jpa

Can I use generics and JPA together?

I am trying to persist objects of four classes to my db. Here's my PersistService class:

```
public class PersistService<T> {
private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("fileUploadProject");

public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}

// Write Client to Database
public static <T> void persist(T obj) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
    et.begin();
    em.persist(obj);
    et.commit();
    em.close();
}
}
```

But then I get into a problem with removing the object. I have the following method in the PersistService class in addition to the above:

```
// Remove an object from the Database if they exist
public static <T> void remove(Long id) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
    <T> obj = em.find(<T>.class, id);
}
```

The final line is giving me a compile time error. I've tried `<T>.class` `T` `Class<T>` and `T.class` as well, but it still gives me a compile time error. Just learning about Type Erasure, is this error because of that? How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: You should try to make a GenericDao and make the child classes extend it

Comment: You never want to have transactions being managed in your `PersistService` methods. You want to manage transaction boundaries based on the logical chunks of business logic. Usually, you will do several to many database operations that you want to either all succeed or all fail - otherwise your system is left in an inconsistent state that is hard to code to and hard to recover from.

Comment: You can't get class type during compile time. you ll spend enough time and resources searching for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have started using a good pattern. The next step is to create a subclass of PersistService for each of your entity types. I will also mention that in the long run you probably want to have a common base class or interface for each of your entities. For example, I will call it `Entity`. This base class (if it is a class rather than interface) can be abstract and can define common methods for all of your entities.

```
public interface Entity {
    long getId();
}
```

You can use the methods defined by `Entity` in your implementation of `PersistService` (which you may find handy as you add more generic entity-related business logic in this base service or elsewhere in your code).

Your entity `A` looks like

```
public class A extends Entity {
}
```

Your `PersistService` becomes

```
public abstract class PersistService<T extends Entity> {
    // Your common methods (persist, remove, etc.).
    public abstract Class<T> getEntityClass();
}
```

Your entity-specific services look like this

```
public class APersistService extends PersistService<A> {
    public Class<A> getEntityClass() {
        return A.class;
    }
}
```

You then use the `getEntityClass()` method when you implement `PersistService.remove()`.

While the entity-specific subclasses solve the problem of getting the specific class object in the face of type erasure, you will find that you end up wanting the subclass to support entity-specific queries as well.

Comment: I tried doing the exact same thing, but in my scenario, the abstract class I am using is implementing a generic interface. The error I get when implementing my "entry specific service" is "Cannot select from a type variable".

Answer (score 0):

I may have the answer you are searching for, well, to have generic type during compile time isn't something that easy. Since java don't allow you to do that directly.

I have a hack myself, can you try something like this ?

> Be sure to handle your exceptions.

```
static <T> Class getGenericType(T t){
    return getType(t);
}
static Class<?> getType(Object o){
    return o.getClass();
}
```