# How can I implement the Repository pattern using Generic Types with Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, repository-pattern

I am trying to find a way I can implement the repository pattern using spring boot with Generic types. So far I looked into this article:

https://thoughts-on-java.org/implementing-the-repository-pattern-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

and tried implementing this solution using generic types based on the solution to this question:

[Using generics and jpa EntityManager methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635734/using-generics-and-jpa-entitymanager-methods)

I attempted to do so using JPA and Hibernate but for me, an error appears when I try returning the class of the entity on the specified type parameter.

the following is my User model using JPA and Hibernate:

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class User extends Model {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String id;

    public String username;
    private String password;

    public User(String username, String password) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

}
```

The following is my interface for basic CRUD operations:

```
package repositories;

import models.Model;

import java.util.UUID;

public interface IRepository<T> {
    void add(T entity);
    void delete(String id);
    void update(T entity);
    T get(String id);
    boolean exists(String id);
}
```

I then created an abstract class for all repositories to avoid repeating myself for all Models.

```
package repositories;

import models.Model;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

public abstract class Repository<T> implements IRepository<T>{

    private EntityManager em;

    public Repository(EntityManager em){
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T entity) {
        em.persist(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(String id) {
        T entity = get(id);
        em.remove(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(T entity) {
        em.merge(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public T get(String id) {
        return em.find(getEntityClass(), id);
    }

    public boolean exists(String id) {
        return em.contains(get(id));
    }

    // link to an explanation can be found at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635734/using-generics-and-jpa-entitymanager-methods
    // when a class extends this class, all is needed is to fill out the method body of to return the class.
    public abstract Class<T> getEntityClass();
}
```

the abstract class is there for me to return the class that belongs to T

and this is the specific repository for Users:

```
package repositories;
import models.Model;
import models.User;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

public class UserRepository<User> extends Repository<User> {

    public UserRepository(EntityManager em) {
        super(em);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<User> getEntityClass() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Ideally, for the getEntityClass method, I would like to return User.class, but I get an error on the IDE saying "Cannot select from type variable". I have looked at a few more questions online and another thing people tried was either put a parameter of type Class or have a member of type Class within the User repository. I tried both methods and it didn't work, any ideas?

Comment: look into PagingAndSortingRepository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`class UserRepository<User>` should just be `class UserRepository`. Otherwise, `User` is just like `T`, a generic type. Not the class `User`.

But you're reinventing the wheel. Learn and use Spring Data JPA, which brings generic repositories, and more.